# linkedin media upload using curl command as binary data

Tags: node.js, linkedin-api

I am trying to post media to linkedin using curl command, how can i pass media as binary data instead of passing filepath?

```
 let header = '';
        if (fileType === 'image') {
          header = `Authorization: Bearer ${token}`;
        } else if (fileType === 'video') {
          header = 'Content-Type:application/octet-stream';
        }
const curlCommand = `curl -i --upload-file ${media.filepath} -H '${header}' '${url}'`;
    child.exec(curlCommand, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
          if (error) {
            console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
            return false;
          }
          if (stderr) {
            return true;
          }
    });
```

Comment: You're using nodejs, why rely on curl?

Comment: axios is not working for linkedin upload

Comment: Any idea why that might be? If it works with curl, it might just be them blocking the axios header

Comment: @KIVOX https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/vector-asset-api?view=li-lms-2022-11&tabs=http#sample-curl-request here they only mentioned curl

Comment: @KIVOX i spoke with technical support team they also recommending to use curl command

Comment: actullay curl command is working with file path but for some reason i want to pass buffer data . becuase storing file in a folder is little out of our flow

Comment: I'm assuming you're reading the file into buffer from elsewhere, so the best approach would be to use the curl `--data-binary` parameter, you can convert the buffer of the image into base64 and use that instead of `--upload-file` as that relies on a filepath.

Comment: @KIVOX ` var bitmap = fs.readFileSync(media.filepath); const fileStream =  new Buffer.from(bitmap, 'base64'); const curlCommand = `curl -i --data-binary ${fileStream} -H '${header}' '${url}'`;`  i tried but its showing an error `curl: no URL specified!`

Comment: The command is most likely too long, try adding the `--data-binary` at the end

Comment: @KIVOX  `curl -i ${fileStream} -H '${header}' '${url}'  --data-binary ` like this ?

Comment: `curl -H '${header}' '${url}' --data-binary ${fileStream}`